# Data Type for Money in Dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, currency, currency-formatting

It is common knowledge that typical floating point data types (aka `float` and `double`) are in Base 2, thus are bad for storing money because Base 2 numbers can not always accurately represent Base 10 numbers like money. To avoid this issue, languages such as Java have implemented data types such as BigDecimal. Is there any similar data type for Dart/Flutter?

Comment: If it's a legitimate concern, use the [decimal](https://pub.dev/packages/decimal) package. That being said, if you are really dealing with money, it shouldn't be stored in your app but instead retrieved/stored elsewhere with your app only retrieving the data from a single source of truth. And if the app isn't concerned with storage and manipulation, a 64-bit floating point like `double` is fine since it only loses precision in a meaningful way when dealing with very large or very small numbers or when a lot of them are combined over time.

Comment: You also could use `int`s that represent the number of cents (or whatever the smallest unit of currency is that you need to handle) instead of the number of dollars.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Abion47 said, the best way to store money would be to use the [decimal package](https://pub.dev/packages/decimal), which is like BigDecimal in Java and has a load of useful features.